# How can I define the relationship (something similar to correlation) between 2 sets of points?

Tags: geometry, statistics, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have 2 sets of points with different number, namely $Blue=\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...(x_n,y_n)\}$ and $Yellow=\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),...(x_m,y_m)\}$, how can I define some indicator to reflect the relationship (similar to correlation) of $Blue$ and $Yellow$?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: To capture the fact that two sets of points (in a metric space) are "close" to each other, you may want to look at the [Earthmover's distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance). It can be explained as follows:

For $z\in{\mathbb R}^2$ and $r>0$ define $D_r(z)$ to be the  disc of radius $r$ centered at $z$. Given an *arbitrary* bounded nonempty set $A \subset{\mathbb R}^2$ one may regard $$A_\epsilon:=\bigcup_{z\in A} D_\epsilon(z)$$ as a smeared out version of $A$. For two such sets $A$, $B\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ one then defines
$$d_H(A,B):=\inf\bigl\{\epsilon>0\bigm| B\subset A_\epsilon\ \wedge \ A\subset B_\epsilon\bigr\}\ .$$
In your case it is about the two sets
$$A:=\bigl\{(x_k,y_k)\bigm|1\leq k\leq n\bigr\},\qquad B:=\bigl\{(u_k,v_k)\bigm|1\leq k\leq m\bigr\}\ .$$

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. By this definition, one extreme point in $A$ can dominantly give a larger increment in the distance (which is not very "correlation-type"). Is it possible to make the extreme points less dominant to the overall result?